# Can you explain how Zend's Action controller operating?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, inheritance

<sub>*Sorry for constantly re-editing my question but looks like this is the only way to ask it properly.*</sub>

My original problem is the following pseudo-code (a controller and it's parent) isn't working as i would like to:

```
class Parent {
    var $data = array();
    public function __construct( OtherClass $otherClass ) {
        $this->data = $otherClass->getData(); //contains some => thing
        $this->init($otherClass->getClassName());
    }
    public function init( $className ) {
        new $className; //new Child
    }
    public function __get( $name ) {
        return array_key_exists($name, $this->data) ? $this->data[$name] : null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->some; //won't return 'thing';
    }
}
```

[fireeyedboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165154/fireeyedboy) helped me a lot (thank you) and pointed out `Zend_Controller_Action` is doing what i want but i can't understand **how they do it?**

---

*Original question*

I know there was some similar questions here but i cannot dump them. Also i know i can reverse the whole process so i can initialize Child first then call `parent::__construct` but this seems unwanted for me. How can i access `Parent` variables easily in my case?

*Update:*

Let me clarify a little bit. `Child` is an arbitrary controller. `Parent` is the mother of all controllers. Many frameworks are doing the same but controllers can utilize their parent controllers variables, methods or objects without calling `parent::__construct` (and therefore filling child class constructors with unnecessary arguments). I don't like to rewrite any of these frameworks but i'd like to understand how they're operating.

Comment: You haven't declared `$some` as a property in that code.  Also, you need to explicitly call the parent constructor.

Comment: Haven't declared? I want to access it via `__get`.

Comment: I think it's an issue with the child class not calling the parent `__get()` method. Why not just store the data as instance properties?

    `foreach($otherClass->getData() as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value
    }`

Comment: @Chris: when i'm echoing `$name` in `__get` it clearly shows what i want to get. It's called properly but `$data` is empty.

Comment: No, because the parent has a magic __get method, which will look into the $data property instead of $some itself.

Comment: @fabrik: Ah yes, did not notice the `__get()` magic method.  Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Orbling Unfortunately i'm stucked @ 5.2.0

Comment: Actually, you're just overriding `Parent::__construct()` which is where the data is being set. You need to explicitly call it or the data array will be empty

Comment: @Chris: do you mean when `init()` called? How can i bypass this?

Comment: It will never work, parent constructor must be called, it is a function like any other so you either add parent::__construct($OBJECT) inside the child constructor either you delete the child constructor so the parent will be automatically called. $this->data is never initialized and never transmited.

Comment: `__construct() { parent::__construct(); echo $this->some; }` is what Chris meant. (Or rather, is what you should do, based on Chris' correct observation).

Comment: `Parent` is not a valid class name. I presume it's not called that in your code?

Comment: @Jon code is clearly a pseudo-one.

Comment: @fabrik: perhaps you could give an indication of what it is you are trying to achieve? At first glance the code looks like it's bending over backwards to achieve it's goals. (But I could be wrong of course).

Comment: @fabrik: I think you might be surprised to find that when you leave out the `child::__construct`, you *can* in fact access the parent variables after the object is created, because you are not _overriding_ the parent constructor then.

Comment: @fireeyedboy yup i am surprised but because sg else: Parent gives me a Catchable fatal error because it isn't seeing it's argument now.

Comment: @fabrik: Ah I see, yes. Either way: you have to give the parent it's arguments. But I'm unsure which _frameworks_ you are referring to? To my knowledge the parent, one way or another, needs it's arguments, unless they are optional arguments. And I don't think you want to call the parent constructor from the child with hardcoded arguments, cause then you are tying them together explicitly (the argument and instantiating the object), making them less flexible.

Comment: @fireeyedboy Now i looked Zend's quickstart and looks like you're half right because Zend's controllers hasn't constructors. Zend, for example doing what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @fabrik: `Zend_Controller_Action` actually _does_ have a constructor (take a look in the source code), but offers an `init()` _hook_ for controllers that extend it. And that hook is what is predominantly used to do ones own instantiation routines, without having to copy the constructor.

Comment: @fireeyedboy i'm simultaneously reading `Zend_Controller_Action` source and [this](http://www.slideshare.net/polleywong/zend-framework-dispatch-workflow) diagram but i can't figure out where's the trick. looks like it's much more complicated than i thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting ANYTHING using controller's construct is generally a **BAD PRACTICE**! Problem lies in your design. What kind of object is OtherClass? Is it DB adapter? Is it ACL? Is it some helper class?

If you need external class in your controller I suggest using action helpers. That's what they are created for ;) Or create an action helper that will fetch this OtherClass from somewhere when needed.

You should NEVER use __construct() to do any of your dirty work. That's what init() is used for. But it has no params. And there is a reason for that - again - you should not inject dependencies like this ;)

**Update:**
Note your class uses discouraged PHP4 member variable definition syntax. Try replacing your `var` with `protected`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you explain a little bit more? I know (experienced) this is a bad practice but i don't know how can i solve this. I'm really stucked at this point now in my design. :(

Comment: Not until you answer `What kind of object is OtherClass? Is it DB adapter? Is it ACL? Is it some helper class? ` :)

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar `OtherClass` is meant to be a Front controller it holds all routing data, parameters, etc. Basically i'd like to pass it to Parent because from then `Parent` (and `Child` too, of course) will know everything about their environment.

Comment: Shouldn't FrontController be the one and only good example of Singleton? :)

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar My front controller *is* a Singleton but this is why i'd like to pass it to my 'action controller' (Parent).

Comment: If it's singleton, you don't need to pass it. you can receive it using `OtherClass::getInstance()`, right?

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar you're right. but unfortunately this is not the same i want to achieve/trying to understand :(

Comment: I read the whole thread once again. I think you're missing the fact that Parent & Child are NOT two different classes. It's actually that the ChildClass (CC) is a Parent. It's not like it has parent "somwhere inside" the class itself is of type ParentClass (PC). If your PC needs something in the constructor, you have to either supply it to your CC or obtain it from some global storage (like Registry) in CC's constructor. You may try to use static variables in PC and access them in CC using PC::$_variable, but you might run into problems (google late static binding)

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar Thank you, again but i think i can't draw up what i'd like to achieve. You were totally right again and your arguments are understandable yet i don't understand how Zend Framework doing the job.

Comment: FrontController is singleton, it's runned, instantiates router and dispatcher. Router selects correct controller based on URL. Dispatcher then instantiates the required controller and sets it up. If needed, additional dependencies are injected using the action helper concept.

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar Thank you for this kind of explanation that was what i was looking for. Now i'm trying to implement it in practice. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 5):

Your child class doesn't call parent constructor. Here's a fix:

```
class Child extends Parent {
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       echo $this->some;
   }
}
```

**Update:** Parent classes' constructors aren't called automatically in PHP. See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> Note: Parent constructors are not
>   called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run
>   a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child
>   constructor is required.

So what you're asking does not happen. Either you have misinterpreted the class structure or how they operate. Note that PHP also supports legacy constructor naming (at least until 5.3.3): If there is no __construct() method in a class, PHP assumes the constructor is named after the class (ie. class Foo { function Foo() {}) treats the Foo() method as constructor).

Comment: @fabrik: take a guess what you should do, to get that to work. Shouldn't be all that difficult to figure out.

Comment: @fireeyedboy do you mean give OtherClass to the Child constructor?

Comment: @fabrik: exactly! :) And pass it along to the parent constructor.

Comment: @fabrik: and if that's not possible, then you should rethink your design. Because in that case the child can hardly be considered a logical descendant of the parent anymore. (Or rather: a logical extension of the inherited class).

Comment: @fireeyedboy i hope my update in the original question maybe helps a little bit what i want to achieve/understand.

Comment: @Fabrik: I updated my answer. To get a better on, you should supply with an example framework, with code showing the exact problem if you're confident that constructor calls actually happen magically there.

Comment: @jmz thanks for the explanation. A good example is Zend where controllers accessing views, helpers, etc. How they do it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Child` class does not call the base constructor.

Incidentally, `Parent` is not a valid class name in PHP. I have changed the class names for clarity. See below:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct(/* what goes here? */);
       echo $this->some;
   }
}
```

However, note the `what goes here?` part: your base class *requires* a reference to an `OtherClass` instance to be constructed. Therefore, since `ChildClass` [IS-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `ParentClass`, it also needs to get such an instance somehow. You will need to either add a parameter to `ChildClass::__construct` and forward the value to `parent::__construct`, or somehow figure out a default value yourself.